# Loop through multiple ComboBoxes to get data JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox

I am trying loop through all the `ComboBox`instances I made in order to get the value the user picks and add that value to a new `ArrayList`, but I am stuck on how to proceed making the loop to get the values.

```
// row for comboboxes
HBox numBox = new HBox();
numBox.setSpacing(16);
numBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
vbox.getChildren().add(numBox);

// setup loop to create 8 combo boxes for user to pick
int comboNum = 8;
ComboBox<Integer> binaryBox = new ComboBox<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < comboNum; i++) {
    binaryBox = new ComboBox<Integer>();
    List<Integer> binaryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    binaryList.add(0);
    binaryList.add(1);

    for (Integer num : binaryList) {
        binaryBox.getItems().addAll(num);
    }

    binaryBox.setValue(0);

    numBox.getChildren().add(binaryBox);
}

// way to get the value from each combo box
ChangeListener<Number> update = 
        (ObservableValue <? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < comboNum; i++){
        //todo
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each [`ComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) has a [`SelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html) from which you can obtain the [`selectedItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty). First, create a list of combo boxes and populate it with your instances of `ComboBox<Integer>`:

```
List<ComboBox<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < comboNum; i++) {
    ComboBox<Integer> binaryBox = new ComboBox<Integer>();
    list.add(binaryBox);
    …
}
```

Later, you can loop through the list to retrieve the selected items using `getSelectedItem()`:

```
for (ComboBox<Integer> combo : list) {
    System.out.println(combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
}
```